# What is a "grid construction" airframe?

Tags: aircraft-design

Could you please help to clarify this question I have in examples of PPL exam questions. It's confusing for me since I'm not able to find "Grid construction" definition at all.

There is usually Truss, Monocoque, Semi Monocoque. And last two are referred as tubular construction, so why the right answer to this question is some Grid construction (and what is it?).

> How is referred to a tubular steel construction with a non
> self-supporting skin?
>
> 1. Semi-monocoque construction.
> 2. (correct) Grid construction
> 3. Honeycomb structure
> 4. Monocoque construction

Comment: Been in aviation 45 years and have never heard of that term.  I would call it tubular truss construction myself. Is that an exam that's been translated from another language possibly?

Comment: is this EU PPL?

Comment: It’s ECQB question bank for PPL in Germany. And the strange thing is that in German version I don’t see such question at all. I wanted to verify translation but could not do this because of that.

Comment: I’ve never heard this term either, but the other answers are incorrect, so by process of elimination…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question in the German version (SPL, 80-AGK, question 3) is

> Wie nennt man eine Stahlrohrkonstruktion mit einer nichttragenden Bespannung? (1,00 P.)
>
> [ ] Schalenkonstruktion
>
> [x] Gitter-Konstruktion oder Fachwerkbauweise
>
> [ ] Bienenwaben-Konstruktion
>
> [ ] Halbschalenbauweise

which is perfectly fine.

If [Aircademy](https://aircademy.com/en/ecqb-ppl/) is correct in showing which countries use the ECQB, then I would assume that most people involved predominantly speak German or another language, and not English, and that these questions were originally designed in German. Many other questions also show unidiomatic or wrong use of English.

To answer your specific question: "Grid construction" is just a wrong translation of "Fachwerkbauweise", which you would call "truss construction".

Comment: Thank you. But where did you find GE version with equivalent questions? When I open ECQB-PPL-80-AGK I don’t see corresponding question. I use Aircademy as well. Thank you.

Comment: On the page I linked above you can find downloads of both English and German practice questions. The questions, from what I can tell, are the same in both languages. Your specific question is in the SPL directory of the zip file, not PPL(A).

Comment: Hi, apologies if I miss something, but when I go there in zip DE under PPLA-ECQB-PPL-80-AGK.pdf I have the file Veröffentlichte Beispielaufgaben where the first questions don't correspond with EN ones. E.g. question 3 is Welches der genannten Materialien weist die größte Festigkeit auf?

Comment: It's SPL/ECQB-PPL-80-AGK-SPL-DE.pdf

Comment: It's like we use really different versions. I just re-checked all. Got to Aircademy, downloaded ECQB-PPL-GE, then inside opened ECQB-PPL-SPL-GE.zip where I have SPL-ECQB-PPL-80-AGK.pdf (not ECQB-PPL-80-AGK-SPL-DE.pdf) with different question 3. Have you used some previous download? So they probably changed something. Crazy.

Comment: Indeed. I've checked download from last year and it's different. Currently in DE section they only published really Samples (with on first page Veröffentlichte Beispielaufgaben) and before it was more comprehensive and corresponded to the EN version (title page 80 – Allgemeine Luftfahrzeugkunde).